# Which data is necessary for PASCAL VOC?

Tags: annotation

Which information is required for consider data as PASCAL VOC?

- Folder
- filename
- path
- size-width
- size-hieght
- size-depth
- segmented
- object-name
- object-boundingbox (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

Is XML a the format required for being considered PASCAL VOC? Or can it be shared as JSON dictionary?

Here's an example of PASCAL VOC XML(from this [src](https://mlhive.com/2022/02/read-and-write-pascal-voc-xml-annotations-in-python)).

```
<annotation>
    <folder>vehicles</folder>
    <filename>ff9435ee-ba7e-4d32-93bb-d931b3d2aca7.jpg</filename>
    <path>E:\vehicles\ff9435ee-ba7e-4d32-93bb-d931b3d2aca7.jpg</path>
    <size>
        <width>800</width>
        <height>598</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>truck</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>7</xmin>
            <ymin>119</ymin>
            <xmax>630</xmax>
            <ymax>468</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>person</name>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>40</xmin>
            <ymin>90</ymin>
            <xmax>100</xmax>
            <ymax>350</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is XML a requirement for being considered PASCAL VOC? Or can it be
> shared as JSON dictionary?

Pascal VOC is in XML Format and COCO is in JSON format. So it can't be created as JSON format.

> Which is this information is required for consider data as PASCAL VOC?

- Folder
- Filename
- Path
- Source
- Size
- Segmented
- Object: name
- Object: pose: Specifies the skewness or orientation of the image. By default, it is specified as Unspecified, which means that the image is not skewed.
- Object: truncated: Tells if an object is fully or partially visible (can be either 0 or 1 respectively).
- Object: difficult: Tells if an object is difficult to recognize from an image (can be either 0 - easy or 1 - difficult).
- Object: bndbox: These are coordinates that determine the location of the object.

Refer: [Comparison of COCO with Pascal VOC](https://towardsdatascience.com/coco-data-format-for-object-detection-a4c5eaf518c5)

Comment: In the referer, the author, says "Pascal VOC is an XML file, unlike COCO which has a JSON file.". But nowhere in PASCAL VOC official homepage is said that:  http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/

Comment: Pascal VOC annotation is in XML Format. Refer Page 18 of VOC Documentation: http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/devkit_doc.pdf

Comment: For the PASCCAL VOC 2012 Challenge, its development kit (page 18), get the results in XML, but the PASCAL VOC 2012 challenge guidelines about "what and how to label" does not strictly mentions XML! See http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/guidelines.html  So, is it strictly necessary to use XML? PASCAL VOC is not a standard syntax. Its a challenge that adopted XML for its object-recognition challenge, and used it in the given development kit used it, right? Here you are some datasets: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/gopalbhattrai/pascal-voc-2012-dataset

Comment: yes pascal voc is not a standard syntax but it's use as XML for annotation was widely accepted afterwards so it's used interchangeably as XML format.

Comment: If this answer helped you pls accept or upvote the answer so that it can be useful for others :)

Comment: Ok, it helped. PASCAL VOC was a challenge. It gave annotation guidelines and the development kit given for the 2012 Challenge, explains that 
"an XML format has been adopted for submission of results".